# What preposition should I use when using two verbs

Tags: prepositions

We use the preposition 'to' with the verb add, and 'from' with the verb remove, example:

1. You need to add a product to your shopping cart.
2. You need to remove a product from your shopping cart.

Now if I combined add and remove, what preposition should I use for them, example:

1. To add or remove a product **to** your shopping cart, hover the mouse over the product.
2. Add/remove a product **from** your shopping cart before payment.

### Update

There is a Persian saying that translate to :

> The easiest way to solve a problem is to eliminate the definition of the problem.

I am not asking for a different way to phrase this sentence, what I am asking is if there is a rule to pick a proposition, something like:

1. Use to, the preposition associated with the first verb
2. User from, the preposition associated with the second verb
3. User to and from

Comment: To me, using "from" sounds right, even after switching "add" and "remove" to see if the more natural-sounding answer only sounds right because of the last option in the list. For both add/remove and remove/add, using "from" sounds right.

Comment: It would be acceptable to say: "To add or remove a product to or from your shopping cart"

Comment: You could say "in your shopping cart".

Comment: To change (or modify)  the contents of your shopping cart...

Comment: *To add or remove a shopping cart item . . .*

Comment: @TinfoilHat - Yeah, that’s better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an excellent question! Unfortunately the English language provides no good solution, as you can see from the other responses. And I would not be surprised if this was a problem in many other languages.

Personally I would go with your option 2: "To add or remove a product from your shopping cart". I wouldn't be happy about it, but options 1 and 3 are worse. More imperfect suggestions:

- To add a product to your shopping cart, or remove an already chosen item,...
- Hover the mouse over a product to add or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The coordination of the verbs fails whatever preposition is used. Consider picking a different verb like *move*.

*To move a product into or out of your shopping cart...*

If you're sticking with *add* and *remove*, consider rephrasing:

*To add a product to or remove one from...*

Answer (score 1):

Now is the time to reimagine your noun *shopping cart* as a [noun adjunct](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012)—functioning as an adjective to modify your noun *product*:

> *To add or remove a shopping cart product . . . *

No prepositions necesssary.